# TranslateX() precisa ser ativado em um <li> e movimentar um <nav>

Tags: css, html5, css3, css-hover, submenu

O problema que estou tendo é que estou fazendo um menu hambúrguer, esse menu hambúrguer, depois de aberto, tem um campo especifico que ao passar o mouse teria que abrir um sub menu, a minha ideia é que esse submenu seja uma segunda  que esteja escondida com um left negativo e que, quando eu estiver com mouse em cima do li com id sub10 ele faça por meio do hover esse  aparecer.
 O problema é que, até onde eu sei, se eu fizer **#sub10:hover{ transform: translateX(valor);** , na realidade eu vou modificar o próprio li que tenha esse id e não a segunda .
 É possível fazer isso que eu pretendo?

***Se precisarem, vou colocar o codigo HTML e o CSS que fiz até agora.***

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="pt-br">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Edgar Müeller</title>
<link href="estilo/estilo.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<!-- Inicio do menu !-->
<script>
function myFunction(x) {
  x.classList.toggle("change");
}
</script>
    <input type="checkbox" id="chec">
    <label for="chec">
    <div class="container" onclick="myFunction(this)">
  <div class="bar1"></div>
  <div class="bar2"></div>
  <div class="bar3"></div>
    </div>
    </label>
      <div class="bg"></div>
    <nav id="principal">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li id="sub10"><a href="#">Obras <span>+</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sobre</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contato</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Estilo das obras</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
  <nav id="obras">
    <ul>
      <li id="sub10"><a href="#">3D Pavement Art</a></li>
      <li id="sub10"><a href="#">Evolution</a></li>
      <li id="sub10"><a href="#">The Caves</a></li>
      <li id="sub10"><a href="#">Unconditional Love</a></li>
      <li id="sub10"><a href="#">The Ark</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
<!-- Fim do menu !-->
</body>
</html>
```

***CSS:***

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* Formatação padrão */
    * {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    }

    a{
        text-decoration: none;
        color: black;   
    }

    body{
        font-family: "Agency FB", Arial, SansSerif;
        font-size: 1.4em; 
        background-color: #F1F1F1;
    }

    ul {
        list-style: none;   
    }
/* Inicio do css icone do menu hamburguer */
.container {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.bar1, .bar2, .bar3 {
  width: 35px;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: #333;
  margin: 6px 0;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.change .bar1 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
}

.change .bar2 {opacity: 0;}

.change .bar3 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
}
/* Fim do css do icone do menu hamburguer */

/* Inicio Menu hamburguer */

#chec
    {
    display: none;  /* esconde o checkbox */
    }

#chec:checked ~ #principal{
    transform: translateX(100%); /* Faz o menu aparecer e reaparecer */
}
#chec:checked ~ .bg{
    display:block;
}
#sub10:hover{
    transform: translateX(300%);
}

#principal{
        background-color: rgba(110, 110, 110, 0.5); /* cor do fundo do menu */
        width: 22%;
        height:100vh; /* unidade base do viewport, pega 100% da pagina */
        left: -22%;
        position: absolute; 
        transition: all .4s; /* Faz a transição/animação do menu */
    }
#obras{
        background-color: rgba(110, 110, 110, 0.5); /* cor do fundo do sub-menu */
        width: 14%;
        height:100vh; /* unidade base do viewport, pega 100% da pagina */
        left: -14%;
        position: absolute; 
        transition: all .4s; /* Faz a transição/animação do menu */
    }

    a{
        display: block;
        padding: 20px 5px;
        color: white;
    }
    a:hover{ /* hover do menu */
        background-color: rgb(176,224,230); 
        color: black;
    }
    label{
        padding: 5px;
        margin: 10px;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 1;
    }
    ul{
        top:70px;
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%
    }
    ul li span{
        float: right;
    }

    .bg{
        width: 100%;
        height: 100vh;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        position: fixed;
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.4);
        display: none;
    }

/* Fim Menu hamburguer */
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não sei se entendi bem mas pelos comentários que tinha no seu código acho que era isso que vc queria. O detalhe é que vc estava usando o `transition` no "item pai" quando na verdade vc tem que usar o `transition` no sub-menu filho...

Precisei fazer algumas mudanças de `position`, e acrescentar uma propriedades na nav do sub-menu, as coisas que eu editei eu deixei por último no código do CSS para ficar fácil para vc ver. Outra coisa não use `width` em `%` nesse menu lateral. isso vai dificultar para vc tratar a responsividade e não faz sentido ele ocupar 22% da largura. Imagine em uma tela ***ultra-wide*** com mais de 4000px de largura, seu menu vai ficar com mais de 800px de largura!! Algo que não faz o menor sentido.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o código da imagem acima.

```css
@charset "utf-8";

/* Formatação padrão */
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}

body {
    font-family: "Agency FB", Arial, SansSerif;
    font-size: 1.4em;
    background-color: #F1F1F1;
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
}

/* Inicio do css icone do menu hamburguer */
.container {
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.bar1,
.bar2,
.bar3 {
    width: 35px;
    height: 5px;
    background-color: #333;
    margin: 6px 0;
    transition: 0.4s;
}

.change .bar1 {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
}

.change .bar2 {
    opacity: 0;
}

.change .bar3 {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
    transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
}

/* Fim do css do icone do menu hamburguer */

/* Inicio Menu hamburguer */

#chec {
    display: none;
    /* esconde o checkbox */
}

#chec:checked ~ #principal {
    transform: translateX(100%);
    /* Faz o menu aparecer e reaparecer */
}

#chec:checked ~ .bg {
    display: block;
}

#sub10:hover {
    /* transform: translateX(300%); */
}

#principal {
    background-color: rgba(110, 110, 110, 0.5);
    /* cor do fundo do menu */
    width: 200px;
    height: 100vh;
    /* unidade base do viewport, pega 100% da pagina */
    left: -200px;
    position: absolute;
    transition: all .4s;
    /* Faz a transição/animação do menu */
}

#obras {
    background-color: rgba(110, 110, 110, 0.5);
    /* cor do fundo do sub-menu */
    /* width: 14%; */
    height: 100vh;
    /* unidade base do viewport, pega 100% da pagina */
    left: -100%;
    transition: all .4s;
    position: relative;
    /* Faz a transição/animação do menu */
}

a {
    display: block;
    padding: 20px 5px;
    color: white;
}

a:hover {
    /* hover do menu */
    background-color: rgb(176, 224, 230);
    color: black;
}

label {
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
}

ul {
    top: 70px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%
}

ul li span {
    float: right;
}

.bg {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
    display: none;
}

/* Fim Menu hamburguer */

#sub10 #obras {
    top: -70px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 170px;
    pointer-events: none;
}

#sub10:hover #obras {
    left: 100%;
    pointer-events: initial
}

#sub10 {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 66px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Inicio do menu !-->
<script>
    function myFunction(x) {
        x.classList.toggle("change");
    }
</script>

<input type="checkbox" id="chec">
<label for="chec">
    <div class="container" onclick="myFunction(this)">
        <div class="bar1"></div>
        <div class="bar2"></div>
        <div class="bar3"></div>
    </div>
</label>
<div class="bg"></div>
<nav id="principal">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li id="sub10">
            <a href="#">Obras <span>+</span></a>
            <nav id="obras">
                <ul>
                    <li id="sub10"><a href="#">3D Pavement Art</a></li>
                    <li id="sub10"><a href="#">Evolution</a></li>
                    <li id="sub10"><a href="#">The Caves</a></li>
                    <li id="sub10"><a href="#">Unconditional Love</a></li>
                    <li id="sub10"><a href="#">The Ark</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sobre</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contato</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Estilo das obras</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Era isso mesmo que queria saber! 
 Quando ao width que você comentou de não usar em %, eu queria saber se tem problema com o height, porque a ideia é ele pegar 100% da pagina, só que o % não estava indo e tinha optado por usar vh, acha que terei algum problema com isso?

Comment: @ViniciusVerissimoBazan cara normalmente 100vh não da problema a não ser em alguns dispositivos mobile onde a barra do browser faz parte dos 100vh entende. Se vc achar que a resposta respondeu sua pergunta considere marca-la como aceita nesse ícone ✔  abaixo das setinhas ao lado da resposta ;)